# Convert numerical solution to RealDigits

Tags: numerics, conversion, digits

It can be determined that `Solve[Gamma[x] == 2*Sqrt[Pi], x]` yields a solution of `x` as `x -> 3.5580029052596..`. What is being asked is: Is there a method that to convert the value of `x` numerical value to one represented by use of RealDigits ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `N`:

```
Solve[Gamma[x] == 2*Sqrt[Pi], x]
RealDigits[x /. N@%]
```

Comment: `Solve` returns the value with greater than `MachinePrecision` so use `RealDigits[Solve[Gamma[x] == 2*Sqrt[Pi], x][[1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]]`